# Euler's method for system of linear ODE's

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, eulers-method

I have the following system:

$$ \begin{aligned} \dot x &= -y \\ \dot y &= x \end{aligned} $$

Given that $(x_i^n,y_i^n)$ are the points obtained for $i=1,2\dots n^2$ using a time-step $h=1/n$ starting at the initial point $(x_0,y_0)=(1,0)$.

I am struggling to find the following limit:
$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} (x_n^n,y_n^n)$$
I can intutively think of the above limit ending up somewhere on the unit circle but I am unable to obtain the value of the exact limit. Pardon if its too simple, but I am surely missing out something. Please help out, thanks in advance.

Comment: You could solve them analytically.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo But I am supposed to solve it by Euler's Method only.

Comment: You could solve them analytically, find the limit and use that to check the solution you get via Euler's method.

Comment: Okay, I will give it a try. Thank you.

Comment: Do you know complex numbers? Then consider $z_n=x_n+iy_n$, the differential equation and Euler step have simple formulas.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Unfortunately I have not learnt to use such an approach. I have only learnt to solve such systems by the method of eigen values. But I doubt if it can help me to find such limits.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I am still stuck :( Can you please suggest me any resources for handling such questions. Currently I am following *A first course in differential equations* by Dennis G. Zill.

Comment: If you can use eigenvalues, then you can also use complex numbers. Your system can be combined to $z'=iz$ and the Euler step similarly to $z_{n+1}=(1+ih)z_n$, which gives a nice geometric sequence. You have, I hope, realized that the task asks you to examine the approximations for $t=1$, that the upper $n$ is not an exponent but an index for the step size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transform $x_1,y_1$ to polar coordinates $r,\theta$. Show then using trigonometric identities that
$$
x_n=r^n\cos(n\theta),~~ y_n=r^n\sin(n\theta).
$$
Show that $r=1+O(h^2)$ and $\theta=h+O(h^2)$ and draw conclusions for the case $nh=1$.

Comment: I got the answer as $(\cos(1),\sin(1))$. Thanks.

Comment: That was the trivial part, the more challenging part is to factor the limit process over the terms to actually show convergence.

Answer (score 1):

$$ \begin{bmatrix} \dot x \\ \dot y\end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\  1 & 0\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y\end{bmatrix}$$

Using [SymPy](http://sympy.org) to compute the [matrix exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential),

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> t = Symbol('t', real=True)
>>> A = Matrix([[ 0,-1],
                [ 1, 0]])
>>> exp(t * A)
Matrix([[cos(t), -sin(t)],
        [sin(t),  cos(t)]])
```

Can you take it from here?